# better way to db using Apche flink for fetch and update data in bulk

Tags: apache-flink

Apache flink : can we able to use hibernate framework to update the database in stream api like data should be processed parallel we have application in that we are fetching processing and updating the records OR any other suggestion for database connectivity.